# Xenomai and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, vxworks, xenomai

I have installed xenomai 2.4.8 in Ubuntu 11.04 with this command:

```
apt-get install libxenomai-dev
```

Now I want test a simple vxWorks program, but when I compile my program, I receive this message:

> Xenomai: vxworksskin or CONFIG_XENO_OPT_PERVASIVE disabled
>   (modprobe xeno_vxworks?)

...and the output of `modprobe xeno_vxworks` is:

> FATAL: Module xeno_vxworks not found

My question is, how can I eanble the xeno_vxworks module?

Answer (score 3):

You installed the xenomai software development libraries, not the xenomai packages themselves. More importantly, a quick check of the xenomai site indicates that you need to compile a kernel module (probably xeno-vxworks) and add it to your kernel before it can work.

The instructions [here](http://www.xenomai.org/index.php/Building_Debian_packages) are for Debian rather than ubuntu, but they should at least point you in the right direction.